# Update Buddypress user’s xprofile input

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I’d like to update what users insert into 3 specific xprofile fields and store it to the database using sanitize_key (force letters lowercase, remove special characters besides "-" and "_"). The values change the way I want to temporarily when I echo them out, but don't store in the database.

Would really appreciate your help! Here's what I have so far

In my functions.php:

```
function expertise_tag_functions_before_save() {
  global $bp;
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
        if ($field == ‘field_24’ || $field == ‘field_26’ || $field == ‘field_27’) {
            $value = sanitize_key( $value );
            $field_label = str_replace(‘field_’, ”, $field);
            xprofile_set_field_data($field_label, $user_id, $value);
    }
  }
};

add_action( ‘xprofile_data_before_save’, ‘expertise_tag_functions_before_save’, 10);
```

- I've tried switching out ‘xprofile_data_before_save for ‘xprofile_data_after_save’ but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your changes are probably being overwritten after the filter hook runs.
You are directly updating the field. You should be changing the submitted profile data.
This is the filter hook which includes access to that data:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'xprofile_data_before_save', array( $this ) );
```

So try:

```
function expertise_tag_functions_before_save( $data ) {

   // make your changes to field values in $data

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I tried that, I got "Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context"